# Oracle: Auto Assigning values with Trigger and Loop

Tags: sql, oracle, for-loop, triggers

I am currently working on a project to simulate a Nursing Home database. So what I want is if a new resident is entered into the database, the trigger will fire and loop through the number of rooms until it finds a room where Occupant has a null value. The trigger should then set the new resid.id as the occupant value and the room_num as the room_num value on the new resident row. Of course if the for loop doesn't find a a vacant room it should output a message saying so.

I apologise for my sloopy code but I've been messing around with this one for a while and haven't been getting any results. At the moment my current error is

```
Error at line 6: PL/SQL: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

Would really appreciate any help you lovely people could offer !

```
Create OR REPLACE TRIGGER Room_Assign
BEFORE INSERT ON Residents
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
FOR Room_Num in 1..MAX(Room_Num) loop
if Rooms.Occupant = NULL
THEN
update Rooms Set Occupant = new.Resid_ID where Occupant = NULL;
SELECT Rooms.Room_Num INTO Residents.Room_Num;
Exit;

END IF;
END loop;
IF new.Resid_ID = NULL
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE("There are no vacant rooms.")
 END;
 /
```

Answer (score 2):

In any kind of enterprise, even the enterprise of "my own fun little project", this would be a prime example of "how to make applications unusable by adding triggers".

Do not use a trigger.

Create a stored procedure, ADD_RESIDENT(), and do all of your logic in that procedure: insert into resident table (including tracking-columns noting time of insert, account which did the insert, etc.), define a cursor that selects all unoccupied rooms FOR UPDATE, fetch the first row returned, update that row with your occupant, close your cursor, and raise exception if no unoccupied rooms were found.  Put everything you want in this procedure: debugging, auditing, logging, whatever - just no COMMIT and no "EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS".

Ensure your end-user-facing application account has read-only access to your database tables, and can only make changes (i.e. insert residents) via execution of stored procedures like this.  If you haven't created a separate user_account for this role, pause and do so now.

I *promise* you will find yourself spending less time building your application in this way - even a single "toy" application built just for your edification. And I also promise you'll be on far fewer !@#$-lists, should any other developers ever come along to contribute to your application.

Comment: Cheers I'll make a procedure out of it !

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing FROM Room in the select clause. Try this:

```
Create OR REPLACE TRIGGER Room_Assign
BEFORE INSERT ON Residents
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
FOR Room_Num in 1..MAX(Room_Num) loop
if (Rooms.Occupant IS NULL)
THEN
update Rooms Set Occupant = new.Resid_ID where Occupant IS NULL;
SELECT Rooms.Room_Num INTO Residents.Room_Num FROM Rooms;
Exit;

END IF;
END loop;
IF (new.Resid_ID IS NULL)
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE("There are no vacant rooms.");
END IF;
END;
 /
```

Comment: 'Error at line 6: PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended'
Is my new error but we're making progress! :)

Comment: Yeah, that's everything I have so far

Comment: New error: 'Error at line 14: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following: := . ( % ;
The symbol ";" was substituted for "END" to continue.'

I added in and END IF statement after the print statement

Comment: Edited again. Pls, check.

Comment: Back to 
Error at line 6: PL/SQL: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
I think I'm gonna take a stab at converting it into a procedure

Comment: Are you sure you executed the last version? It is strange that error disappeared and appeared again. Also, can you add the structure for Residents and Rooms table?